# How to integrate an already-existing .rb file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still learning Ruby on Rails, but have a general question about using a link on a Rails view to trigger a ruby program to run. In other words, rather than type "ruby filename.rb" at the command prompt, I want a link in my Rails view to execute the code in filename.rb, when it's clicked.

I know this is a bit of hack, but I'm trying to learn one step at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 1.9.x you can use Process.spawn;

```
Process.spawn("ruby #{Rails.root}/my_ruby_file.rb")
```

Comment: What is the best way to initiate this with a link_to element in a view?

Comment: I use this in one of my rails apps, in the view I link to an action called 'launch_my_ruby_file' which simply executes this line of code. In my app I capture the output to a txt file and redirect the view to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Copy that file in the lib directory  and use `require "already-existing.rb"` in your rails view helper and call the methods from that file in your view .